# Change my MySQL SQL statement to MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to convert this MySQL statement, to MS SQL to run on SQL 2008 R2?

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(summary.date) as epoch_date,
round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.group != '' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as total,
round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.group = 'eastern' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as eastern,
round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.group = 'western' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as western,
round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.group = 'central' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as central
FROM summary, meters
WHERE summary.webmeterID = meters.webmeterID
AND date BETWEEN
DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 YEAR) 
AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP by date
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT

CASE

WHEN DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',summary.[date])>0

THEN DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',summary.[date])

ELSE

0

END as epoch_date,

round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.[group] != '' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as total,

round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.[group] = 'eastern' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as eastern,

round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.[group] = 'western' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as western,

round(SUM(CASE WHEN meters.[group] = 'central' THEN kWh ELSE 0 END),2) as central

FROM summary, meters

WHERE summary.webmeterID = meters.webmeterID

AND [date] BETWEEN

DATEADD(year,-3,GETDATE())

AND DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())

GROUP by [date]
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'."

Comment: [date] and [group] are reserved words in SQL Server 2008 and if used as column names (which is not recommendable!) should be written in square brackets ([]).